# Visual Studio 2008 crashing on close if windows layout altered

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, settings

My VS2008 is crashing whenever I close it, if I have changed how windows are arranged (e.g. docking the Output window somewhere else). I have switched off all plugins etc. I suspect that the settings file for the layout is corrupted or something. Where is it, and would delteing it possibly help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to apply the following hotfix:

> **[KB960075 - VS Dev Environment crash after undocking windows or changing layouts](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB960075)**

Note that a hotfix has not undergone regression testing, so there might be issues with it. Install it only if it solves your problem.

Comment: For anyone still interested, the download has moved.

[Link to https://connect.microsoft.com/](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=16927)

Answer (score 1):

To see if it is your user settings - back up your settings using the tools options then reset and see if that sorts out your problem.  If it does, then you can slowly restore your old settings 1 section at a time to see which causes the issues.  At that point you have to reset and restore all the ones that worked again.

I had to do this once when my find / replace dialog box disappeared.  If I used the short cut or menu the dialog box must have been appearing off the screen.  Doing the above sorted out the issue

Comment: I've tried re-importing old settings, but the problem remains. If I reset all settings, then it doesn't crash, but I have a whole load (resharper etc) and would prefer not to start from scratch...

Comment: ...and now it has started again, despite resetting all settings from scratch :(